# User Defined Function to calculate unique random number based on criteria in another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to make a UDF that calculates a unique random number that has not been used for each criteria.

So, example: You have a column of 10 cells, 5 with "Apple" and 5 with "Pear". I want the formula to generate a number that has not been used for "Apple" before. So you can have a 2 for Apple and 2 for Pear, but not 2 for Apple twice. Another parameter would be a maximum number, which would be a cell or value.

This is what I have so far, however it just results in a "Value" error when entered.

The Col variable is how many columns the Rand result is away from the Criteria column. I was thinking I could just instead have it be a defined range, but I didn't know how to do that.

```
Function RandBetweenIntCrit(Lowest As Long, Highest As Long, Criteria As Range, Criteria_Range As Range, Col As Long) As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim yRg As Range

For Each xRg In Criteria_Range
    If xRg = Criteria Then
        If yRg Is Nothing Then
            Set yRg = xRg.Offset(0, 0 + Col)
        Else
            Set yRg = Union(yRg, xRg.Offset(0, 0 + Col))
        End If
    End If
Next xRg

Do
    R = Lowest + Int(Rnd() * (Highest + 1 - Lowest))
        For Each C In yRg
            If R = C Then Exit For
        Next C
Loop Until C Is Nothing

RandBetweenIntCrit = R
Application.Volatile
End Function
```

EDIT -

I have fiddled with the code a bit more, and managed to get this one to at least generate a number.

However, when it finds a number that doesn't match the Criteria (and so should be ignored) it results in an #VALUE error

```html
Function RandBetweenIntCrit(Lowest As Long, Highest As Long, Criteria As String, Prev_Range As Range, Col As Long) As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim yRg As Range

For Each xRg In Prev_Range
    If xRg.Offset(0, Col) = Criteria Then
        If yRg Is Nothing Then
            Set yRg = xRg
        Else
            Set yRg = Union(yRg, xRg)
        End If
    End If
Next xRg

Do
    R = Lowest + Int(Rnd() * (Highest + 1 - Lowest))
        For Each C In yRg
            If R = C Then Exit For
        Next C
Loop Until C Is Nothing

RandBetweenIntCrit = R
Application.Volatile
End Function
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016, Version 2004 (build 12730.20270)

Comment: A unique random number isn't a random number. You would have to create a list of remaining numbers within the scope and then select one of them at random. So there is an element of uncertainty. But the last one remaining isn't random at all.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I am okay with that.

Comment: How long do you need to store the "taken" numbers? Can they be written to a sheet (which sheet)? May they be lost when the session is closed? Or do you need a function to clear the store from memory?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. The Taken numbers would be shown in the cells above this formula, which are definied by me when I enter it, A$1:A3 For example

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to correct the #Value error in the previous edit by Adding an Iff Statement to the RandBetween Calculation to account for their being no entries in the yRg Range.

This UDF now runs as expecting. It generates a Random Number between two Integars, that has not already been used for a cell with the chosen criteria.

```html
Function RandBetweenIntCrit(Lowest As Long, Highest As Long, Criteria As String, Prev_Range As Range, Col As Long) As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim yRg As Range

    ' For each cell in the Previous Number range, check to see if the Criteria range matches the given specification
    For Each xRg In Prev_Range
        If xRg.Offset(0, Col) = Criteria Then
            If yRg Is Nothing Then
                Set yRg = xRg
            Else
                ' Add the cell to the Exclude List
                Set yRg = Union(yRg, xRg)
            End If
        End If
    Next xRg
    
    ' Randomly calculate a number between a lowwest and highest number, exlucing any numbers on the Exclude List
    Do
        R = Lowest + Int(Rnd() * (Highest + 1 - Lowest))
            ' If the Exclude list is empty, then random number
            If yRg Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                ' Recalculate until unique number achieved
                For Each C In yRg
                    If R = C Then Exit For
                Next C
            End If
    Loop Until C Is Nothing

    RandBetweenIntCrit = R
    Application.Volatile
End Function
```